# Returning the count in a join but not returning a result for each joined table, possible?

Tags: postgresql

I have this simply query that returns 100 rows, each row is for 1 course:

```
select c.*
from courses c
  join schools s ON s.id = c.school_id
```

How can I get the # of students who's favorited the course, if I try this:

```
select c.*, st.id
from courses c
  join schools s ON s.id = c.school_id
  join students st ON st.favorite_course_id = c.id
```

In the above query, if I had say 100 courses, I will get many more results back since I am joining with the students table that has 1000's of records.

I still want to get back 100 results, 1 row for each course, but I want to know the total # of students who have favourited a particular course.

Comment: Why is there a join to `schools` if you don't use any columns from the table? Just to filter implicitly? Makes a difference for the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery instead of a join:

```
SELECT
  c.*,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM students st WHERE st.favorite_course_id = c.id) AS fav_count
FROM courses c
JOIN schools s ON s.id = c.school_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lateral join like the below :

```
select c.*, q.cnt
from courses c
  join schools s ON s.id = c.school_id
  join lateral (select count(*) cnt from students st where st.favorite_course_id = c.id) q on true
```

Comment: is this better than a subquery?

Comment: @Blankman depends on the actual query, if your actual query is the above it may not differ (significantly) it performs better when queries get more complex (consider a scenario where you need multiple values from the students table )

Comment: @Blankman You should not be asking *which is better*. The SO community **cannot** answer that question. Test them both on your hardware with your query and your data. Run each several times in different order and with different normal system loads. Then stress test them. With that you, and only you (or your team), can answer which is better.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is with `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT sub.*
FROM  (
   SELECT c.*, count(st.favorite_course_id) AS fav_count
   FROM   courses c
   LEFT   JOIN students st ON st.favorite_course_id = c.id
   GROUP  BY c.id  -- being the PK to cover all c.* in the aggregation
    ) sub
JOIN   schools s ON s.id = c.school_id  -- why this join ???
```

Depending on undisclosed information, this may or may not be faster.